# Can I migrate data from an AWS DynamoDB to a new Global Table using export/import to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

We want to migrate some of our DynamoDB tables to the new global tables.  I saw one article that said we can use the export/import to S3 using a data pipeline to migrate our data.  Has anyone actually done this successfully?  Is the data format the same for the export file so it can be read on import to the global table?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is possible.

In addition to using export/import can you create a Data Pipeline in such a way that you can do a direct copy from source to destination (Global) table.